# Обеденение таблиц в одну

Tags: mysql

Нужно как то вывести в одну таблицу 4 разные по количеству столбцов таблиц.

Т.е. там где нет столбца. просто пустая строка

Первое что пришло это UNION но количество столбцов разное, не прокатывает

Еще нужно как то сделать чтобы id само собой формировалось от 1 до количества строк

```
SELECT `medical_msk`.*,
`category`.`category` AS `category_name`,
`type`.`type` AS `type_name`
FROM `medical_msk`
LEFT JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id`=`medical_msk`.`category`
LEFT JOIN `type` ON `type`.`id`=`medical_msk`.`type`;

SELECT `medical_spb`.*,
`area_spb`.`area` AS `area_name`,
`category`.`category` AS `category_name`,
`type`.`type` AS `type_name`
FROM `medical_spb`
LEFT JOIN `area_spb` ON `area_spb`.`id`=`medical_spb`.`area`
LEFT JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id`=`medical_spb`.`category`
LEFT JOIN `type` ON `type`.`id`=`medical_spb`.`type`;

SELECT `medical_reg`.*,
`region`.`region` AS `region_name`,
`city`.`city` AS `city_name`,
`category`.`category` AS `category_name`,
`type`.`type` AS `type_name`
FROM `medical_reg`
LEFT JOIN `region` ON `region`.`id`=`medical_reg`.`region`
LEFT JOIN `city` ON `city`.`id`=`medical_reg`.`city`
LEFT JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id`=`medical_reg`.`category`
LEFT JOIN `type` ON `type`.`id`=`medical_reg`.`type`;

SELECT `medical_oth`.*,
`country`.`country` AS `country_name`,
`city_oth`.`city` AS `city_name`,
`category`.`category` AS `category_name`,
`type`.`type` AS `type_name`
FROM `medical_oth`
LEFT JOIN `country` ON `country`.`id`=`medical_oth`.`country`
LEFT JOIN `city_oth` ON `city_oth`.`id`=`medical_oth`.`city`
LEFT JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id`=`medical_oth`.`category`
LEFT JOIN `type` ON `type`.`id`=`medical_oth`.`type`;
```

Comment: а как сделать столбец который будет сам нумероваться от 1 до количества строк?

Comment: оформил в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Верно, для `union [all]` необходимо, чтобы количество столбцов в объединяемых запросах было одинаковое, но всегда можно дополнить запрос с меньшим количеством полей до нужного количества константами, например NULL. Именно поэтому использовать в запросах * никогда не стоит. Всегда перечисляйте выбираемые поля, у вас не убудет, но запрос будет работать и при добавлении столбцов в используемые в запросе таблицы.

```
select a,b,c from tabc
union all
select a,b,NULL from tab
union all
select a,NULL,NULL from ta
```

Чтоб получить нумератор, можно воспользоваться переменными.

```
select @row_num := @row_num+1 as id,a,b,c 
from (
  select a,b,c from tabc
  union all
  select a,b,NULL from tab
  union all
  select a,NULL,NULL from ta
) s, ( SELECT @row_num :=0 ) r
```